# How to tune / choose the preference parameter of AffinityPropagation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I have large dictionary of "pairwise similarity matrixes" that would look like the following:

`similarity['group1']`:

```
array([[1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 1.        , 0.09      , 0.09      , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.09      , 1.        , 0.94535157, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.09      , 0.94535157, 1.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ]])
```

In short, every element of the previous matrix is the probability that `record_i` and `record_j` are similar (values being 0 and 1 inclusive), `1` being exactly similar and `0` being completely different.

I then feed each similarity matrix into an [`AffinityPropagation`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation.html) algorithm in order to group / cluster similar records:

```
sim = similarities['group1']

clusterer = AffinityPropagation(affinity='precomputed', 
                                damping=0.5, 
                                max_iter=25000, 
                                convergence_iter=2500, 
                                preference=????)) # ISSUE here

affinity = clusterer.fit(sim)

cluster_centers_indices = affinity.cluster_centers_indices_
labels = affinity.labels_
```

However, since I run the above on multiple similarity matrixes, I need to have a generalised `preference` parameter which I can't seem to tune.

It says in the docs that it's by default set as the median of the similarity matrix, however I get lots of false positives with this setup, the mean sometimes work sometimes gives too many clusters etc...

---

e.g: when playing with the preference parameter, these are the results I get from the similarity matrix

- `preference = default # which is the median (value 0.2) of the similarity matrix`: (**incorrect** results, we see that the record `18` shouldn't be there because the similarity with the other records is very low):

  ```
   # Indexes of the elements in Cluster n°5: [15, 18, 22, 27]

   {'15_18': 0.08,
   '15_22': 0.964546229533378,
   '15_27': 0.6909703138051403,
   '18_22': 0.12,    # Not Ok, the similarity is too low
   '18_27': 0.19,    # Not Ok, the similarity is too low
   '22_27': 0.6909703138051403}
  ```
- `preference = 0.2  in fact from 0.11 to 0.26`: (**correct** results as the records are similar):

  ```
   # Indexes of the elements in Cluster n°5: [15, 22, 27]

   {'15_22': 0.964546229533378,
   '15_27': 0.6909703138051403,
   '22_27': 0.6909703138051403}
  ```

---

**My question is**: How should I choose this `preference` parameter in a way that would generalise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **naive and brute force** `grid search` solution can be implemented as such if a connection is scored less than a certain threshold (0.5 for example), we'd re-run the clustering with an adjusted value of the `preference` parameter.

A naive implementation would be like the following.

---

First, a function to test whether a clustering needs tuning, the threshold  being `0.5` in this example:

```
def is_tuning_required(similarity_matrix, rows_of_cluster):
    rows = similarity_matrix[rows_of_cluster]

    for row in rows:
        for col_index in rows_of_cluster:
            score = row[col_index]

            if score > 0.5:
                continue

            return True

    return False
```

---

Build a preference range of values against which the clustering would run:

```
def get_pref_range(similarity):
    starting_point = np.median(similarity)

    if starting_point == 0:
        starting_point = np.mean(similarity)

    # Let's try to accelerate the pace of values picking
    step = 1 if starting_point >= 0.05 else step = 2

    preference_tuning_range = [starting_point]
    max_val = starting_point
    while max_val < 1:
        max_val *= 1.25 if max_val > 0.1 and step == 2 else step

    preference_tuning_range.append(max_val)

    min_val = starting_point
    if starting_point >= 0.05:
        while min_val > 0.01:
            min_val /= step
            preference_tuning_range.append(min_val)

    return preference_tuning_range
```

---

A normal `AfinityPropagation`, with a `preference` parameter passed:

```
def run_clustering(similarity, preference):
    clusterer = AffinityPropagation(damping=0.9, 
                                    affinity='precomputed', 
                                    max_iter=5000, 
                                    convergence_iter=2500, 
                                    verbose=False, 
                                    preference=preference)

    affinity = clusterer.fit(similarity)

    labels = affinity.labels_

    return labels, len(set(labels)), affinity.cluster_centers_indices_
```

---

The method we would actually call with a similarity (1 - distance) matrix as an argument:

```
def run_ideal_clustering(similarity):
    preference_tuning_range = get_pref_range(similarity)

    best_tested_preference = None
    for preference in preference_tuning_range:
        labels, labels_count, cluster_centers_indices = run_clustering(similarity, preference)

        needs_tuning = False
        wrong_clusters = 0
        for label_index in range(labels_count):
            cluster_elements_indexes = np.where(labels == label_index)[0]

            tuning_required = is_tuning_required(similarity, cluster_elements_indexes)
            if tuning_required:
                wrong_clusters += 1

                if not needs_tuning:
                    needs_tuning = True

        if best_tested_preference is None or wrong_clusters < best_tested_preference[1]:
            best_tested_preference = (preference, wrong_clusters)

        if not needs_tuning:
            return labels, labels_count, cluster_centers_indices

     # The clustering has not been tuned enough during the iterations, we choose the less wrong clusters
    return run_clustering(similarity, preference)
```

---

Obviously, this is a brute force solution which will not be performant in large datasets / similarity matrixes.

If a simpler and better solution gets posted I'll accept it.